# JDOM Element creation

Tags: java, xml-namespaces, jdom

I am new to JDOM, and am having trouble creating a document.  The problem is that I want
to be able to add Elements that do NOT have the "xmlns" attribute.  I am using JDOM 1.1

All of the examples I have found show the output *without* the "xmlns".  Here is a simple
code fragment, along with its output:

```
      Namespace jwNS = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.javaworld.com");
      Element myElement = new Element("article", jwNS);
      Document doc = new Document(myElement);
      myElement.addContent(new Element("title").setText("Blah, blah, blah"));

// serialize with two space indents and extra line breaks
try {
  //XMLOutputter serializer = new XMLOutputter("  ", true);
  XMLOutputter serializer = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());
  serializer.output(doc, System.out);
}
catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println(e);
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article xmlns="http://www.javaworld.com">
  <title xmlns="">Blah, blah, blah</title>
</article>
```

What I want is to just have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article xmlns="http://www.javaworld.com">
  <title>Blah, blah, blah</title>
</article>
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your desired example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article xmlns="http://www.javaworld.com">
  <title>Blah, blah, blah</title>
</article>
```

This means that all child elements of `<article>` have the same namespace as `<article>`, i.e. namespaces are inherited from parents to children.  That means you need to specify `jwNS` for all of your child elements, i.e.

```
myElement.addContent(new Element("title", jwNS ).setText("Blah, blah, blah"));
```

When rendering the XML output, JDOM should then omit the explicit namespace from `<title>`, since it inherits it from `<article>`.

By using just `new Element("title")`, you're saying that you want no namespace on `<title>`, and so JDOm has to add an explicit `xnmns=""` attribute in order to override the inheritance of the `jwNS` namespace from the `<article>` parent.

Comment: Three years later, and this still helped me. Thanks for the response. Seems XML isn't as died out as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your element by using:

```
Element myElement = new Element("article");
```

instead of

```
Element myElement = new Element("article", jwNS);
```